# Django FormField: How to set `max_length` and other properties in a baseclass

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to set `label` and `max_length` inside `IBANField` to generalize it and use it somewhere else. `validate_iban` is a validator function.

Here is what I have now. It's ok, but not what I want.

```
class IBANField(CharField):
    default_validators = [validate_iban]


class SepaForm(forms.Form):
    iban = IBANField(max_length=34, label=_('IBAN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way, but this is one solution:

```py
class IBANField(CharField):
    default_validators = [validate_iban]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['label'] = _('IBAN')
        kwargs['max_length'] = 34
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SepaForm(forms.Form):
    iban = IBANField()
```

Comment: Maybe w/o return before `super`

Comment: Thats right, my bad